# Complex gapless sound loop in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, audio, wav

I have a WAV music file that I want to loop in Flash Pro. However, I am not sure how to work with this track, which has an **opening part** and a **looping part**.

The audio file would be 'divided' in three points: *A*, *B* and *C*. The **looping part** would be all the audio between points *B* and *C*, while the audio between *A* and *B* would be the **opening part**, which would be played only once.

I tried to divide the WAV into two files: A-B would be the `intro` file, and the B-C the `looping` file, so that right after the `intro` sound finishes, the `looping` sound begins.
Both files are on the library (right now I'm only focusing on local files).

To summarize, here's the AS3 code:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var introMusic:Sound = new heroIntro();
var loopingMusic:Sound = new heroLoop();
var musicChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
musicChannel = introMusic.play();
musicChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,continueMusic);

function continueMusic(e:Event):void{
    musicChannel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,continueMusic);
    musicChannel= introMusic.play();
    musicChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,continueMusic);
}
```

The loop is completely gapless, but the transition between the intro and the looping parts makes an annoying gap sound. How could I make that transition gapless?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to avoid the gap sound by playing the 2nd Sound in a different SoundChannel a second or so before the 1st Sound finishes playing.  It's not an elegant solution, but it might work.  Perhaps something like this:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var introMusic:Sound = new heroIntro();
var loopingMusic:Sound = new heroLoop();
var introChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var loopingChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var hasBegunLooping:Boolean = false;
introChannel = introMusic.play();

function update():void{ //called every tick
    if(!hasBegunLooping && introChannel.position > introMusic.length - 1000){
        loopingChannel = loopingMusic.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
        hasBegunLooping = true;
    }
}
```